# HMAC MD5 on Windows Phone 7 / Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, md5, hmac

I'm trying to generate a HMAC_MD5 algorithm on Windows Phone 7. As as I discovered , HMACMD5 class in not implemented in WP7. On the other hand, I found a MD5 Silverlight library ( http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5 ), but I cannot generate a new MD5 signature based on **predefined key**. Any hints ?
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Hint: showing your code will make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If the Silverlight library won't work (though as Matt points out, without code it's hard to say what might be going wrong), [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) supports just about every encryption type out there and it has [Compact Framework](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2011/07/28/BouncyCastleCryptoInTheCompactFramework.aspx) support, so it's likely to work fine in Windows Phone.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with MD5 for Silverlight library, just doesn't cover my needs. I need to create a HMAC MD5 signature, but the library cover only MD5 algorithm, not HMAC.

Comment: @AlexTroto i have also same question. some days back i saw a post which says getting hash of (data+key) responds the same result as salted md5 results. Please let me know if you found a solution.